# Upgrading PHP 5.4.9 to 5.5 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-13.04

I am currently running PHP 5.4.9 on Ubuntu 13.04 and I want to upgrade to 5.5 because of the new password_* library and other features.  What is the easiest and least painful way to upgrade?

Comment: is your current installation installed from source or from yum?  if installed from source you can use config.nice to keep the same options when compiling

Comment: i installed using tasksel

Comment: Maybe include what research you've done into upgrading and what you've tried, and what errors you've come across.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no easy and painless way to upgrade now.  You installed from the official sources, and it's definitely easiest to stick with them.

General ways to get an updated version are:

- Wait for the next release.
- Use the version from backports.  Unfortunately, PHP 5.5 is not available on raring-backports yet (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring-backports&keywords=php5).
- If you're not running a production site, one option is to manually download and install the packages from the next version - in this case, saucy (13.10; it appears that saucy has the newer version: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/php5).  But this won't be kept up-to-date with newer versions, may have dependencies, won't get security support until saucy is officially released, and (worst-case) may not work at all on raring (13.04).
- Add the saucy repositories and use apt-pinning to ensure that you only upgrade the php5 package (and dependencies).  This isn't easy, IMO, and doesn't give you security updates.
- Install from source. But then you have to either install a non-packaged version or build your own packages.  Then you get the version you want, but this isn't easy like installing a package, nor does it take the pain out of later upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I will stay with 5.4.9, and use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat - password_* functions that are compatible older versions.